# StackOverflowException: 'Exception_WasThrown' Error

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

While I'm trying to connect MySql with Entity Framework Core (without password) program throws **StackOverflowException: 'Exception_WasThrown**. Here is my Context and running code.

```cs
    public class LauncherContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("Server=localhost;Database=dbname;user=root;password=");
        }

    }
```

```cs
using (LauncherContext context = new LauncherContext())
{
  return context.Users.SingleOrDefault(user => user.Username == "userUsername");
}
```

Comment: Pls , post your filter too

Comment: @Sergey i added filter.

Comment: Please add the stacktrace from the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mean window authentication your connection string should be like this:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;IntegratedSecurity=yes;
Uid=auth_windows;
```

Comment: Now system throw **System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'The option 'IntegratedSecurity' is not currently supported.'** error.

Comment: check one more time  your server name and database name

Comment: and check if you have installed MySql.Data.MySqlClient. Add  this namespace to using.

Comment: I installed MySql.Data.MySqlClient but which file I should add this to using? DbContext?

Comment: yes, add  using MySql.Data.MySqlClient to file where is your connection string

Comment: and check this  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/windows-pluggable-authentication.html#windows-pluggable-authentication-installation